# Opening file from path without knowing full file name (python)

Tags: python, string, filenames

I am trying to open a file using the full path, but I don't know the complete name of the file, just a unique string within it.

```
i = identifier
doc = open(r'C:\my\path\*{0}*.txt'.format(i), 'r')
```

Now obviously this doesn't work because I'm trying to use the wildcard along with the raw string. I have had a lot of trouble in the past trying to use file paths *without* preceding them with 'r', so I'm not sure of the best way to handle the incomplete file name. Should I just forget raw string notation and use '\\\\' for the file path?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html is the best way to look up filenames that you don't know - `open` doesn't work with wildcards. Also, the best way to work with the backslashes in your DOS pathnames is to use `os.path.join` to build the path.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper What if I just do `path=glob.glob(r'path/*identifier*.txt')` then `doc=open(path, 'r')`?

Comment: `glob.glob` returns a possibly empty list, so you can't directly open its return value. But `paths=glob.glob(...); if paths: doc = open(paths[0], 'r')` is basically right. It appears that `glob` is forgiving about which file dividers you use.

Answer (score 2):

From the question comments:

```
import glob
import os

i = "identifier"
basePath = r"C:\my\path"

filePaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(basePath,'*{0}*.txt'.format(i)))

# Just open first ocurrence, if any
if filePaths:
    print "Found: ", filePaths[0]
    doc = open(filePaths[0], 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
    
def foo(path):
    _, _, files = next(os.walk(path))
    print(files)
    
files = foo(r'C:\Users') 
files[1]
```